# v8 persistent setWeak callback not getting called

Tags: c++, v8

Using Google's v8 C++ library, I have tried creating a v8::UniquePersistent instance on the heap which holds an internal pointer to some memory that was allocated in C++, and called SetWeak()  on the Persistent to specify a callback, which would do the necessary cleanup by deallocating the memory that the internal pointer in the Persistent refers to when that handle is no longer needed by the javascript engine.   Although the creation of the Persistent seems to work,  I am finding that my callback function is never getting invoked.

I am completely stumped here.  Any ideas what might I be doing wrong?

Comment: From the v8 docs: "There is no guarantee as to when or even if the callback is invoked. The invocation is performed solely on a best effort basis. As always, GC-based finalization should not be relied upon for any critical form of resource management!" See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24107280/v8-weakcallback-never-gets-called

Answer (score 2):

The `callback` is invoked only when the object is `garbage` collected. Try this example:

```
void callback(v8::WeakCallbackData<v8::Object, int> data)
{
   Local<Object> val = data.GetValue();
   int* ptr = reinterpret_cast<int*>(val->GetAlignedPointerFromINternalField(0));
   delete ptr;
   fprintf(stdout, "Deleted internal object!\n");
}

void main()
{
  using namespace v8;

  // Enable garbage collection
  const char* flags = "--expose_gc";
  v8::V8::SetFlagsFromString(flags, strlen(flags));

  Isolate isolate = Isolate::New();
  isolate->Enter();
  HandleScope scope(isolate);
  Eternal<v8::Context> context;
  Local<ObjectTemplate> ctx_template  ObjectTemplate::New(isolate);
  context.Set(isolate, Context::New(isolate, nullptr, ctx_template);
  
  Local<ObjectTemplate> obj_template = ObjectTemplate::New(isolate);
  obj_template->SetInternalFieldCount(1);
  Local<Object> obj = Local<Object>(isolate, obj_template->NewInstance());
  obj->SetAlignedPointerInInternalField(0, new int);
  UniquePersistent<Object> persistent(isolate, obj);
  persistent->SetWeak(nullptr, callback);

  //...do something with persistent

  persistent.Reset();

  isolate->RequestGarbageCollectionForTesting(v8::Isolate::kFullGarbageCollection);
  // You should see output from the callback
  // i need to add more words to pass edit word num check...
}
```